# Simple Addition Question

Tags: arithmetic

In basic math, when adding there is the notion of carry. For example if you have $9999+9999$, since $9+9=18$ the $1$ is leftover and carried to the top. Is there some formula that gives us the total number carried? So in the case of our example, it would be $4$.

Comment: In $a+b$, it can be found by $|S(a)+S(b)-S(a+b)|$ which can express the total number of carries in that expression. $S(n)$ is the sum of digits for $n$.

Comment: In the sum of $a=11$ and $b=29$, the number of carries is $1$ but $S(a)+S(b)-S(a+b)=(1+1)+(2+9)-(4+0)=2+11-4=9$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MXYMXY Yes, this doesn't really make sense

Comment: Obviously, I'm not correctly remembering the formula. But there was a connection. I just don't remember what.

Comment: Every time you carry, you reduce the sum of the digits by 9.  Take MXMXY's formula and divide by 9.

Comment: @DougM Would you add that as an answer?

Comment: I think MXMXY/DougM observation works in any base: the result will always be $\dfrac{S(a)+S(b)-S(a+b)}{n-1}$ if we are working in base $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem) says the number of carries when adding $m + n$ in a prime base $p$ is the largest integer $k$ such that $p^k$ divides the binomial coefficient ${m + n \choose m}$.  Unfortunately, $10$ is not a prime.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.